# How do I check uploaded file is empty?

Tags: php, oop, methods, upload, image-uploading

I am attempting to do some validation on uploaded images. When I check to see if any images have been selected and uploaded it should return an error message if no images have been uploaded. But in my method it always returns `false`.

Heres the method:

```
class event{

        private $dbh;
        private $post_data;


        public function __construct($post_data, PDO $dbh){
                $this->dbh = $dbh;
                $this->post_data = array_map('trim', $post_data);

        }

public function checkValidImages(){
            $errors = array();

            if(empty($this->post_data['event-images'])){
                $errors[] = 'Please select at least one image to upload.';
            }

            if(count($errors) > 0){
                return $errors;
            }else{
                return FALSE;
            }

        }
```

and calling it here:

```
// Check all images are valid
        $images = new event($_FILES, $dbh);
        var_dump($imageErrors = $images->checkValidImages());
```

The `var_dump()` returns `bool(false)`.

heres the form:

```
<form name="submit-event" action="submit-event.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="large-12 columns no-padding">
<p>Select images for this event</p><br />
<input type="file" class="right" name="event-images[]" size="50" multiple="multiple" />
</div>
</form>
```

So why is my method returning false even when I don't select any images.

Comment: The var_dump() returns bool(false) which means there is no error. This is how you have defined your function.

Comment: I've just realised that if I don't select an image to upload and do a count of `$_FILES['event-images']['name']` it returns `1` instead of 0. Which is odd. Surely if I didn't select any thing it should return zero?

Answer (score 0):

When an HTML file input is left empty, the browser will still submit the name of the form element, so you will still get that entry in the $_FILES array, but with an error code of `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` and a filename of `""`.

You should check [the error code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) anyway as lots of things can go wrong. So your validation code becomes something like:

```
$numOkayFiles = 0;
$numIntendedFiles = 0;
foreach ($_FILES['event-images']['error'] as $errorCode) {
    $numIntendedFiles += ($errorCode != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE);
    switch ($errorCode) {
    case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
        $numOkayFiles++;
        break;
    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
        $errors[] = 'Your file was bigger than the maximum allowed size.';
        break;
    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
        // ignore
        break;
    default:
        $errors[] = 'A problem occured during file upload.';
    }
}
if ($numIntendedFiles == 0) {
    $errors[] = 'Please select at least one image to upload.';
}
```